# Merkle–Hellman knapsack cryptosystem - My exam

Tags: cryptography

I'm learning about Merkle-Hellman cryptosystem.

Here is my question : Why chose q 
:
 [image]

```
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Merkle–Hellman_knapsack_cryptosystem
```

Thanks all.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it should be migrated to http://crypto.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is in the next few sentences of that same Wikipedia article:

*q is chosen this way to ensure the uniqueness of the ciphertext. If it is any smaller, more than one plaintext may encrypt to the same ciphertext. Since q is larger than the sum of every subset of w, no sums are congruent mod q and therefore none of the private key's sums will be equal.*

So in short q is chosen to ensure uniqueness of the ciphertext which is important. If I have message `a` which encrypts to `b` and message `c` also encrypts to `b` then there is no unique decryption for `b`. `b` could be either `a` or `c`. It is important that encryption/decryption algorithms are one-to-one from plaintext to ciphertext otherwise it becomes difficult to encrypt/decrypt - there would be an element of guessing involved.

Comment: But I think, how to prove this by mathematically.

Comment: If you want to go into the math this should probably go to http://crypto.stackexchange.com/. The math isn't particularly hard in this case and I'd recommend it as an exercise, but that's not really emphasis of stackoverflow.com.